# Check if the output returned by a query contains a string/number or not

Tags: php, mysql, string, moodle

I am working on Moodle but have a **php-mysql** related doubt which is turning out to be complicated, thanks to the lack of my knowledge.

I have a query which returns the output fine. Using  IF-ELSe condition I need to check if there is a combination of one of the fields containing a string and one of the field containing a number.

The fields I m checking are of the following type in the database table.

```
 element - varchar(255)
 value - longtext
```

This is my query which returns the o/p as mentioned below:

Query

```
    $scormstatus = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT sc.*, s.name AS activityname FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track AS sc JOIN mdl_scorm AS s ON s.id = sc.scormid WHERE sc.scormid = '" .$activityid. "' AND sc.userid = '" .$userid. "' AND sc.attempt = '".$scormattempt->attempt."'");
     foreach($scormstatus as $status)
      {
         echo "<br/>".$status->element."**".$status->value."<br/>";
         if(is_numeric($status->value))
         {
           if($status->element = 'cmi.core.score.raw' && $status->value != '0')
           {
              echo "<br/>Score";
           }    
           else
           {
                if($status->element = 'x.start.time' && $status->value != '0')
                {
                  echo "<br/>Started";
                }
           }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
         cmi.core.lesson_location**2
         Score

         cmi.core.lesson_status**incomplete
         cmi.core.score.max**50
         Score

         cmi.core.score.min**0
         cmi.core.score.raw**0
         cmi.core.total_time**00:00:22.00

         x.start.time**1334767290
         Score
```

Now as you would have seen that even though I'm checking for a condition which is a combination of 'cmi.core.score.raw' and value greater than 0 it still prints 'Score' for all records and never goes in the else part.

Ideally the output I'm looking forward to see is something like this

IDEAL O/P:

```
     cmi.core.lesson_location**2
     cmi.core.lesson_status**incomplete
     cmi.core.score.max**50
     cmi.core.score.min**0
     cmi.core.score.raw**0
     cmi.core.total_time**00:00:22.00
     x.start.time**1334767290
     Started
```

My guess is that it isn't recognizing the value field which is a number in my IF--ELSE case and hence always ends up going in the wrong IF part.

Any guesses as to what is happening. Thanks in advance

Comment: Also it's not necessary to put tags in the title

Comment: Yeah dont know why I added that. Its not there now. Any ideas on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
if($status->element = 'cmi.core.score.raw'
```

needs to be:

```
 if($status->element == 'cmi.core.score.raw'
```

A single `=` is for assignment, while two `==` is for comparison.

Comment: Right I had used that before but because it dint give the right result for one of the possibilities I changed it to single '=' and then never switched it back. I think that should make it work.

Comment: It gives right value for all possibilities except one. Instead of 'Score' it shows 'Started' with `==` How ever if I change it to `=` just in that case it gives me the right output. In this case I 'm checking for `$status->element == 'cmi.core.lesson_status'` and `$status->value == 'completed'`. The database has this value still it goes in the other else part which is wrong. any ideas?

Comment: Please post your full code, current output and expected output - I can't read your mind. Without seeing what you're actually doing, try replacing `!=` with `!==` to ensure its not thinking `"incomplete"` and `"0"` are the same.

Comment: The code, current o/p n xpected o/p(IDEAL O/P) is all there in the question. Its strange that for some case it works with `=` and for others it works with `==` but even I feel that `==` is the right way to go maybe

Comment: It only works with `=` as a side-effect - it's not doing what you think.

Comment: Its working with `==` for now with all possibilities. It was apparently my database problem which after a lot of testing I encountered wasn't pulling out the right data in some cases. Hence single or double `=` anyway was giving wrong results. Thanks for your help. Everything is working fine now. Sorry for the confusion.